# How to extract date from time series and convert it to date in R

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have a dataset consisting of 4 variables namely date,Gold price,crude price and dollar price. I converted the class of the data to time series using ts() function. After converting, the dates got changed into some value. I am able to retrieve the dates from converted values using as.Date() function.Now I want to  replace the date values by date itself in the ts object's date variable.

```
         #CONVERTING DATA FRAME TO TIME SERIES OBJECT.
          Gold.ts <- ts(Gold,start=Gold$DATE[1])
          head(Gold.ts)


         #OUTPUT.

        DATE GOLD.PRICE CRUDE DOLLAR.INR
  [1,] 13152      533.9 63.42     44.705
  [2,] 13153      526.3 62.79     44.600
  [3,] 13154      539.7 64.21     44.320

 head(as.Date(index(Gold.ts)))
 [1] "2006-01-04" "2006-01-05" "2006-01-06" "2006-01-07" "2006-01-08" "2006-  01-09"
 Gold.ts$DATE <- as.Date(index(Gold.ts)) # This won't work because $ is not   acceptable to extract variables from a time series object.
 index(Gold.ts) <- as.Date(index(Gold.ts)) #This should work but gives error. How to display date instead of values in time series object i.e Gold.ts?
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Use the `[[` or `[` for these cases, but I think you need `xts` or `zoo` i.e. `xts(Gold.ts[,2:3], order.by = as.Date(Gold.ts[,1]))`

Comment: Vector auto regressive(VAR)  doesn't work in xts package. VAR is used for predicting multivariate time series.

Comment: Ohh, ok, thanks for the info

Comment: have you laoded the `zoo package? The `base` implementation of `as.Date` has no default for origin for its integer flavour, so would have thrown error. try `base::as.Date(13152)` . However, `index` would work if zoo was loaded.